# Creating List Item Sharepoint REST API Javascript returns Error 500

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-api

I've currently got a script that, if I don't include the parameter Mission_Number - will work just fine to create a new list item. Whenever I try to pass that parameter, I get an error 500 (Internal Server Error).

Here is my list setup:

Ticket Number = Single Line of Text

DV = Choice

Tail Number = Choice

Mission Number = Single Line of Text

Here is my javascript:

```
var hostUrl = "mysite";
var listName = "Tickets";

$(document).on('click', '#ticket_submit', function() { 
    var ticket_number = $("#ticket_number").val();
    var dv = $("#dv_select").val();
    var tail_number = $("#tail_number").val();
    var mission_number = $("#mission_number").val();
    

    var itemProperties = {'Ticket_Number':ticket_number,'DV':dv,'Tail_Number':tail_number,'Mission_Number':mission_number};
    console.log(itemProperties);
    CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, hostUrl, itemProperties, function () {
        alert("New Item has been created successfully.");
    }, function () {
        alert("Ooops, an error occured. Please try again.");
    });
});

//
function CreateListItemWithDetails(listName, webUrl, itemProperties, success, failure) {
    var itemType = GetItemTypeForListName(listName);
    itemProperties["__metadata"] = { "type": itemType };
    
    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(itemProperties),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": digest // getting this from a function not shown here
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is an example of the JSON that I am passing that does not work:

```
{Ticket_Number: "2020-310-0001", DV: "ccxcc", Tail_Number: "12312", Mission_Number: "123123"}
```

Its odd to me that the ticket_number value is passing just fine, but the mission_number one is not. I have double checked in the sharepoint that I am using the proper column names as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I accidentally had the ticket number column set as requires unique.. Problem has been fixed.